# como passar dados em formato json para uma select?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Olá, recebo dois JSON, um de marcas outro de modelos.

```
{
"data": {
    "JEEP": 40,
    "LAND ROVER": 46,
    "LAMBORGHINI": 42,
    "LIFAN": 43,
    "IVECO": 94,
    "ASIA MOTORS": 5,
    "AM GEN": 1,
    "ENVEMO": 23,
    "WAKE": 77,
    "NISSAN": 59,
    "FIBRAVAN": 26,
    "MASERATI": 52,
    "ROVER": 65,
    "BUGGY": 9,
    "CADILLAC": 14,
    "LADA": 45,
    "LEXUS": 47,
    "CROSS LANDER": 17,
    "PLYMOUTH": 61,
    "VW - VOLKSWAGEN": 75,
    "CHERY": 13,
    "FIAT": 25,
    "SATURN": 68,
    "MAZDA": 54,
    "FORD": 27,
    "MG": 49,
    "CHRYSLER": 15,
    "SMART": 79,
    "ALFA ROMEO": 4,
    "SEAT": 69,
    "RELY": 83,
    "AUDI": 6,
    "TOYOTA": 73,
    "MERCEDES-BENZ": 55,
    "JAGUAR": 39,
    "ROLLS-ROYCE": 84,
    "GM - CHEVROLET": 29,
    "GREAT WALL": 30,
    "HYUNDAI": 34,
    "DAEWOO": 18,
    "MATRA": 53,
    "PONTIAC": 62,
    "FOTON": 82,
    "TESLA": 92,
    "EFFA": 21,
    "LANDWIND": 86,
    "FYBER": 28,
    "SUZUKI": 71,
    "ASTON MARTIN": 81,
    "PEUGEOT": 60,
    "HAFEI": 32,
    "FERRARI": 24,
    "BABY": 93,
    "SAAB": 67,
    "SUBARU": 70,
    "TROLLER": 74,
    "VOLVO": 76,
    "CITROEN": 16,
    "ISUZU": 35,
    "BUGRE": 10,
    "MAHINDRA": 51,
    "RENAULT": 64,
    "ACURA": 95,
    "MERCURY": 56,
    "JPX": 38,
    "DODGE": 20,
    "CBT JIPE": 11,
    "KIA MOTORS": 41,
    "LOTUS": 48,
    "DAIHATSU": 19,
    "MITSUBISHI": 57,
    "SHINERAY": 80,
    "INFINITI": 91,
    "WALK": 78,
    "PORSCHE": 63,
    "BMW": 7,
    "JAC": 36,
    "LOBINI": 44,
    "DKW VEMAG": 85,
    "MCLAREN": 2,
    "MINI": 50,
    "CHANGAN": 12,
    "GURGEL": 31,
    "HITECH ELETRIC": 96,
    "AGRALE": 3,
    "MIURA": 58,
    "TAC": 72,
    "JINBEI": 37,
    "SSANGYONG": 66,
    "BRM": 8,
    "GEELY": 87,
    "PUMA": 89,
    "CHANA": 88,
    "ENGESA": 22,
    "HONDA": 33,
    "RAM": 90
},
"status": "ok"
```

}
esse é de modelos

```
{
"data": {
    "DUCATO-10": 8,
    "MAREA": 17,
    "DUCATO-8": 10,
    "TEMPRA": 25,
    "DUCATO-15": 9,
    "ELBA": 12,
    "ARGO": 34,
    "GRAND SIENA": 31,
    "COUPE": 5,
    "MOBI": 33,
    "CRONOS": 36,
    "SIENA": 21,
    "TIPO": 26,
    "BRAVA": 2,
    "FREEMONT": 14,
    "IDEA": 15,
    "UNO": 27,
    "PANORAMA": 29,
    "LINEA": 16,
    "OGGI": 30,
    "TORO": 32,
    "FIORINO": 13,
    "BRAVO": 3,
    "DUNA": 11,
    "STRADA": 23,
    "PALIO": 18,
    "CINQUECENTO": 4,
    "PUNTO": 20,
    "STILO": 22,
    "147": 28,
    "500": 1,
    "PREMIO": 19,
    "DOBLO": 6,
    "DUCATO": 7
},
"status": "ok"
```

}

quero passar eles para select, para ficar como na imagem abaixo
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

1ª duvida é como passar desse formato json para a select

2ª ao escolher marcas, popular os modelos.

estou tentando usar nesse jeito, mas está dando erro:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    colors = {
      "data": {
          "JEEP": 40,
          "LAND ROVER": 46,
          "JINBEI": 37,
          "SSANGYONG": 66,
          "BRM": 8,
          "GEELY": 87,
          "PUMA": 89,
          "CHANA": 88,
          "ENGESA": 22,
          "HONDA": 33,
          "RAM": 90
      },
      "status": "ok"
    };

  $.each(colors, function(key, value) {
      $('#divSelect').append($("<option/>", {
          value: value,
          text: key
      }));
  });
 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="divSelect"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Não está funcionando, pois você está adicionado os options a uma div, não a um select. Tente fazer seu html assim:

```
<div id="divSelect"><select id="idSelect"></select></div>
```

E troque o "#divSelect" por "#idSelect" no seu javascript.

Comment: olá, agora no select apareceu DATA e STATUS. Como fazer para aparecer as marcas e excluir da lista esses dois(data e status).

Comment: consegui fazendo assim $.each(colors.data, function(key, value) { ......
vou ver como popular agora.

Answer (score 0):

Tinha esse código aqui, vê se te ajuda :)

```js
var dic = {
   'Cachorro': ['Poodle', 'Bulldog', 'Pinsher'],
   'Gato': ['Gato - Siames', 'Gato - sei la'],
};

$('#animais').on('change', function() {
   var selectValue = $(this).val();
   $('#racas').empty();
   
   for (i = 0; i < dic[selectValue].length; i++) {
      $('#racas').append("<option value='" + dic[selectValue][i] + "'>" + dic[selectValue][i] + "</option>");
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="animais">
  <option value="" disabled selected>Selecione um animal</option>
  <option value="Cachorro">Cachorro</option>
  <option value="Gato">Gato</option>
</select>

<select id="racas">
  <option value="" disabled selected>Selecione uma raca</option>
</select>
```

Comment: vou tentar trabalhar em cima do seu código. obrigado